# Fire and forget entry/accept mechanism in Ada

Tags: asynchronous, ada

Is there a pattern for a fire and forget mechanism in Ada?  When I call a task entry, I don't want the caller to be blocked until the message has been processed.  I would like the task to be asynchronous.  What I've tried is

```
loop
    select
        accept xxx(params) do
           -- save the parameters in a queue
        end accept;
        ...
    else
        -- pick the next item off the queue and process it
    end select;
end loop;
```

It looks like a clumsy mechanism.  Maybe fire and forget is the wrong term.  I've also tried one task filling up the queue and another taking entries off the queue.  Is there a better way of implementing asynchronous tasks in Ada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re using Ada 2012, the way to go would be to use [Ada.Containers.Unbounded_Synchronized_Queues](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-28.html) (or the [Bounded](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-29.html) version): your user code calls `Enqueue`, your server task calls `Dequeue` which blocks if the queue is empty.

If not, the normal approach would be to use your own protected object to encapsulate a queue (which is how the Ada 2012 packages do it). Something like

```
package Parameters is new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Positive, Parameter);
protected Queue is
   procedure Put (P : Parameter);
   entry Get (P : out Parameter);
private
   The_Queue : Parameters.Vector;
end Queue;

protected body Queue is
   procedure Put (P : Parameter) is
   begin
      The_Queue.Append (P);
   end Put;
   entry Get (P : out Parameter) when not The_Queue.Is_Empty is
   begin
      P := The_Queue.First_Element;
      The_Queue.Delete_First;
   end Get;
end Queue;
```

and then

```
task body Server is
   P : Parameter;
begin
   loop
      Queue.Get (P);
      --  process P
   end loop;
end Server;
```

Comment: Guess it is time to update my compiler - I'm still using Ada95.